# Channel categories and metadata

Tags: categories, seo, seo-lite, metadata

For the entries I'm using SEO Lite module but what can I do for categories landing pages metadata except default from SEO Lite module? Conditionals are not the best choice for because I have about 120 categories so I need to have that somehow automated with relation to categories.

Currently I have

```
{if segment_2!="" && segment_3==""}
{embed="includes/.header-product" default_title="{segment_2_category_name} Collection"}
{if:elseif segment_3!=""}
{embed="includes/.header-product" default_title="{segment_2_category_name} {segment_3_category_name}"}
{if:else}
{embed="includes/.header-product"}
{/if}
```

Looking towards any tips.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just create additional Category Custom Fields? They are quite limiting but a Text Input for Keywords and a Text Area field should suffice for meta data.

You can read more about them here:

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/channels/category_field_management.html

Answer (score 2):

Below final solution based on category custom fields (thanks to Mark), SEO Lite module, Low Seg2Cat and GWcode Categories plugin in case someone will have similar problem which I had.

```
{if segment_2!="" && segment_3==""}
    {exp:gwcode_categories show="{segment_2_category_id}" custom_fields="yes" style="linear"}
        {embed="includes/.header-product" 
            default_title="{if meta_title==""}{segment_2_category_name} Collection{if:else}{meta_title}{/if}" 
            default_keywords="{meta_keywords}" 
            default_description="{meta_description}"
        }
    {/exp:gwcode_categories}
{if:elseif segment_3!=""}
    {exp:gwcode_categories show="{segment_3_category_id}" custom_fields="yes" style="linear"}
        {embed="includes/.header-product" 
            default_title="{if meta_title==""}{segment_2_category_name} {segment_3_category_name}{if:else}{meta_title}{/if}" 
            default_keywords="{meta_keywords}" 
            default_description="{meta_description}"
        }
    {/exp:gwcode_categories}
{if:else}
{embed="includes/.header-product"}
{/if}
```